# How to add the values of one array within a for loop to another and push it to an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I have the following code which calculates a tip percentage that is relative to the amount of the bill. I was instructed to create a method within the object itself to store the values much easier. However, I will need the function again in another code. To avoid repetition I have created a separate function, calculateTip, and a separate for loop to iterate over the bills within the John object.

I have figured out how to calculate the separate tips and store those values within the tips array.

**Now I would like to take the original bill amount and add them to its corresponding tip and push that to the array.**

*(So that the finalBills array should show the sums of : [142.6, 57.60 etc...])*

Here is what I have come up with so far...

```
var john = {
    patron: 'John',
    bills: [
        124,
        48,
        180,
        268,
        42
    ],
    tips: [],
    finalBills: []
}

function calculateTip(bill) {
    if (bill < 50) {
        percentage = (20 / 100);
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
        percentage = (15 / 100);
    } else {
        percentage = (10 / 100);
    }
    return percentage * bill;
};

// console.log(john.bills.length);

for (var i = 0; i < john.bills.length; i++) {
    var bill = john.bills[i];
    console.log(bill);

    var tips = calculateTip(bill);
    var roundedTips = tips.toFixed(2);
    john.tips.push(roundedTips);
    console.log('These are the tip amounts: ', roundedTips)

    var finalBill = (roundedTips + bill);
    console.log('Final amounts: ', finalBill)
};

console.log(john)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Return_value) you get a string instead of a number, try using [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#Examples), also if the method is to be in the object you could 
create a [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Patron {
  constructor(patron, bills) {
    this.patron = patron;
    this.bills = bills;
    this.tips = [];
    this.finalBills = [];
  }

  calculateTip(bill) {
    let percentage;
    if (bill < 50) {
      percentage = (20 / 100);
    } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
      percentage = (15 / 100);
    } else {
      percentage = (10 / 100);
    }
    return percentage * bill;
  }

  calculateFinalBill() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
      var bill = this.bills[i];
      //console.log(bill);
      var tip = this.calculateTip(bill);
      var roundedTips = parseFloat(tip.toFixed(2));
      this.tips.push(roundedTips);
      //console.log('These are the tip amounts: ', roundedTips);

      var finalBill = (roundedTips + bill);
      //console.log('Final amounts: ', finalBill);
      this.finalBills.push(finalBill);
    }
  }
}

const john = new Patron('john', [124, 48, 180, 268, 42]);
john.calculateFinalBill();
console.log(john.finalBills);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I definitely understand what you did here and it patches things up.